# Function to extract substring from a string with multiple delimiters - python

Tags: python-3.x, regex, pandas, function

I have a column with string that contains delimiters and I would like to create a function to extract substring only for the string that contains the delimiters

Current

```
EMAIL               TITLE
johnson.k@abc.com   Marketing Analyst
linda.m@abc.com     501.Software Engineer.MG3 
kwami.k@abc.com     Product Researcher
george.w@abc.com    Managing Director
jessie.a@abc.com    64.Legal Consultant.I44
hiroda.t@abc.com    Hardware Analyst.
```

I would like to extract the substring in between the "." delimiters only for the string with delimiters. Else, the text should remain the same.

```
EMAIL               TITLE                       NEW_TITLE
johnson.k@abc.com   Marketing Analyst           Marketing Analyst
linda.m@abc.com     501.Software Engineer.MG3   Software Engineer
kwami.k@abc.com     Product Researcher          Product Researcher
george.w@abc.com    Managing Director           Managing Director 
jessie.a@abc.com    64.Legal Consultant.I44     Legal Consultant
hiroda.t@abc.com    Hardware Analyst.           Hardware Analyst.
```

I have tried to create a function with the following code but it does not seem to be working

```
def clean_title(text):
    match = re.search(r"\.(.*?)\.", text)
    if match:
        return match.group(1)
    else:
        return text

df['NEW_TITLE'] = df['TITLE'].apply(clean_title)
```

appreciate any form of help, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a replacing approach:

```py
df['NEW_TITLE'] = df['TITLE'].str.replace(r'^[^.]*\.([^.]+)\..*', r'\1', regex=True)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/4bMjuB/1). The regex matches all occurrences of

- `^` - start of string
- `[^.]*` - zero or more non-dot chars
- `\.` - a dot
- `([^.]+)` - Group 1: one or more non-dot chars
- `\.` - a dot
- `.*` - the rest of the line (any zero or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible)

And replaces with Group 1 value.